# QUrlQuery append?

Tags: c++, qt, append, qt5, qurl

Is it possible to use QUrlQuery to append data without striping the url?

Using the code bellow will strip everything after the "?" and
the result is:

```
https://foobar.com/Info.xml.aspx?userdata=1234
```

I would like to get:

```
https://foobar.com/Info.xml.aspx?user=jack&userdata=1234
```

---

```
QUrl url("https://foobar.com/Info.xml.aspx?user=jack&");
QString data = "1234"; 

QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("userdata", data);
url.setQuery(query);
```

I'm asking because i need to make multiple calls, every time adding a new parameter and "building" the url from scratch every time is annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the query and then add the item:

```
QUrl url("https://foobar.com/Info.xml.aspx?user=jack&");

QString data = "1234";
QUrlQuery query(url.query());
query.addQueryItem("userdata", data);
url.setQuery(query);

qDebug()<<url;
```

Output:

```
QUrl("https://foobar.com/Info.xml.aspx?user=jack&userdata=1234")
```

Comment: Was that simple, damn.
Thank you!